# Searching for specific information in one CSV file derived from two other CSV files (python)

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a nutrition database with 3 different CSV files. After cleaning, the first file contains two columns: nutrient id, and nutrient name; the second file contains two columns: food id, and food description (name); and finally, the third file contains three columns: nutrient id, food id, and amount (of the nutrient in this food). Since there are several millions of lines, I can't every time open each file separately, and check which id corresponds to which nutrient or food. So I am trying to create a code, which will read all three files, then search for matches in id columns for both nutrient (from the first file) and food (from the second file), replace id with a name, and return 3 columns: nutrient_name, food_name, amount. Now, there is a complication, namely: in the 1 and 2 files, the lines are sorted by id-s, while in the third file (with amount) the lines are sorted by nutrient_id (meaning that food id-s column is chaotic). So I can't just merge three files, or replace id columns with name columns in the third file... 
Here is an example of my code, which does not return what I need. I am quite stuck at this because I can't find the answer on the internet. Thanks!

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

"""
Created on Fri Nov  8 17:38:45 2019

@author: user
"""
import pandas as pd 
#%% reading csv files 

#read the first scv file with nutrient_name, nutrient_id
df1 = pd.read_csv('nutrient.csv', low_memory=False)
print(df1)

#read specific columns from the first csv file
df1 = pd.read_csv('nutrient.csv', usecols = ['id', 'name'], low_memory=False)
df1.rename(columns={'name' : 'nut_name'}, inplace = True)
print(df1)

#read the second scv file with food_id and food_name , read specific columns 
df2 = pd.read_csv('food.csv', usecols = ['fdc_id', 'description'], low_memory=False)
print(df2)

#read the third csv file with food_id, nutrient_id and nutrient amount
df3 = pd.read_csv('food_nutrient.csv', usecols=['fdc_id','nutrient_id', 'amount'], low_memory=False)
print(df3)

#%% create a list of rows from each csv file 
# Create an empty list 1
Id_list =[] 
Name_list = []

# Iterate over each rowin first csv file 
for index, rows in df1.iterrows(): 

# append the list to the final list 
Id_list.append(rows.id)
Name_list.append(rows.nut_name)


# Print the list 
print(Id_list[:10])
print(Name_list[:10])  

# Create an empty list 2
Food_id_list =[]
Food_name_list =[] 

# Iterate over each rowin seconf csv file 
for index, rows in df2.iterrows(): 

# append the list to the final list 
Food_id_list.append(rows.fdc_id)
Food_name_list.append(rows.description)

print(Food_id_list[:10])
print(Food_name_list[:10])

# Create an empty list 1
Amount_list =[] 
Name_list1 = []
Food_name1 = []

# Iterate over each rowin third csv file 
for index, rows in df3.iterrows(): 

# append the list to the final list 
Amount_list.append(rows.amount)
Name_list1.append(rows.nutrient_id)
Food_name1.append(rows.fdc_id)

# Print the list 
print(Amount_list[:10])
print(Name_list1[:10])
print(Food_name1[:10])

#%% search in the third csv only rows, where amount of the certain nut in certain food is not empty 
value 
for i in Name_list:
   #for j in Food_name_list:
    if i in df3['nutrient_id']:
        print(df3.loc[i, 'amount'])
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what SQL was created for. SQL's `join` command joins multiple tables.
Having played around with pandas a lot, I would highly suggest picking up a simple SQL course or first try going through a simple `SQL join` tutorial as this is very much an introductory problem in SQL.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check out SQL then (never worked with it before)